# Typescript : recursive template literal type, allow both string and specific chaining

Tags: typescript, typing, template-literals

**MCVE**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s5uy47?file=index.ts%3AL25

*(try using the autocomplete on the parameter of the function `f` to see what it achieves)*

I am trying to create a recursive template literal to check if the strings given to a function satisfy the REST approach of my API.

So far, I managed to make simple examples work (in the code, those would be `version` & `health/check`).

What I would like to do is allow routes with parameters in it.

In the provided code, the route `users/[PARAM]` is accepted with no problem, and offered in the autocomplete of the parameter.

But `users/12` is not accepted. For me, the issue is at the end of the `Dive` type :

```
`${k & DiveKey}/${typeof param | string}`
```

If I use `${k & DiveKey}/${typeof param}` I get the actual result.

If I use `${k & DiveKey}/${string}` then it works, but I don't get `users/[PARAM]` in the autocomplete of the parameter, which "hides" the path from the developer using the function.

My question is : **is there a way to keep `users/[PARAM]` in the autocomplete, and accept `users/12` as a parameter ?**

Thank you in advance for the response.

**Code**

```js
export type RestEndpoint = Dive;

const param = '[PARAM]' as const;
type DiveKey = string | number;

type Dive<T = typeof API_REST_STRUCTURE> = keyof {
    [k in keyof T as T[k] extends Record<any, any>
        ? `${k & DiveKey}/${Dive<T[k]> & DiveKey}`
        : T[k] extends typeof param
        ? `${k & DiveKey}/${typeof param | string}`
        : k]: any;
};

const API_REST_STRUCTURE = {
  version: false,
  health: { check: false },
    users: param,
};

function f(p: RestEndpoint) {}

f('version');
f('health/check');
f('users/[PARAM]');
f('users/12');
```

**EDIT 1** : This is what is seen when using `${string}` :

[image]

And this is what is seen with `typeof param` (see that `users/12` is not accepted)

[image]

Comment: As explained, it "hides" the URL from the autocomplete, which means the user won't be able to see he can call it when using autocomplete.

Comment: @jcalz I have updated my question with pictures for a better understanding of the issue

Comment: Seems to be a missing feature described at [ms/TS#41620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41620).  So far my workarounds haven't helped.  Maybe some crazy generic function will do it

Comment: I can understand why it is not proposed in the autocomplete, since the possibilities are infinite. I'm not trying to "force"-show it. What I would like is simply to make my type ACCEPT the `/12` ending, not to offer it. As long as it offers `/[PARAM]`, the dev can *see* that the endpoint is available. The nuance is subtle I guess, but do you get my point  ?

Comment: I understand what you're talking about, yes, but it's not currently supported.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WK3P8W) work for you?  It's  "crazy generic function" so I'm not happy with it, but I think it acts as you'd like.  If this fully addresses the question I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It seems to do the job, I will try to understand it on my own, but may I ask first : it seems to "count" the types in your `Replace` type (S, D, A, F, R) : does that mean I am restricted to a given number of `[PARAM]`s ? for instance, will `users/[PARAM]/friends/[PARAM]/family/[PARAM]/members/[PARAM]/body/[PARAM]/value` work ?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I think I got it, it's like a `split` function in JS to see if `[PARAM]` appears in the string, right ? Anyways it really seem to do the job, please create an answer so that I can accept it !

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently "pattern" [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) with placeholders like `` `${string}` ``, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598) aren't shown in auto-suggest / auto-complete lists.  This is a missing feature of TypeScript, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41620).  For now, if you want to see suggestions corresponding to such types, you'll need to work around it.

---

One approach is to make two types: one with `"[PARAM]"` in it, and one with `string` in it.  Then we make your `f()` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in such a way that the `"[PARAM]"` version will be suggested, but any `string` will be accepted in its place.

So let's change `Dive` so that it only generates the `["PARAM"]` version:

```
type Dive<T = typeof API_REST_STRUCTURE> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Record<any, any>
    ? `${K & DiveKey}/${Dive<T[K]> & DiveKey}`
    : T[K] extends typeof param
    ? `${K & DiveKey}/${typeof param}`
    : K]: any;
};

type RestEndpointSchema = Dive;
// type RestEndpointSchema = "version" | "health/check" | "users/[PARAM]"
```

So `RestEndpointSchema` has `"[PARAM]"` in it. And then we can write a utility type to replace `"[PARAM]"` with `string` wherever it appears:

```
type Replace<
    T extends string, S extends string, D extends string,
    A extends string = ""
> = T extends `${infer F}${S}${infer R}` ?
    Replace<R, S, D, `${A}${F}${D}`> : `${A}${T}`

type RestEndpoint = Replace<RestEndpointSchema, typeof param, string>
// type RestEndpoint = "version" | "health/check" | `users/${string}`
```

That `Replace<T, S, D>` is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that takes an input `T` and produces a version where every appearance of `S` is replaced with `D`.  So `RestEndpoint` is `Replace<RestEndpointSchema, typeof param, string>`.

And now here is the generic function:

```
function f<T extends string>(
    p: T extends RestEndpoint ? T : RestEndpointSchema
) { }
```

The type of `p` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on `T`.  When you call `f()` start typing an input, that input will probably not be a valid `RestEndpoint`.  And therefore the compiler will infer `T` as something that doesn't extend `RestEndpoint`, and so the type of `p` will evaluate to `RestEndpointSchema`.  So you'll see the suggestions including `[PARAM]`:

```
f(); // f(p: "version" | "health/check" | "users/[PARAM]"): void
f('')
// ^ health/check
//   users/[PARAM]
//   version
```

And then when you start typing, it will accept any valid `RestEndpoint`, including the input starting with `"users/"` without `"[PARAM]"` in it:

```
f('version'); // okay
f('health/check'); // okay
f('users/12'); // okay
```

but it still rejects invalid inputs:

```
f('dog'); // error
```

---

That's about as close as I can get to your desired behavior.  It's a shame that there's no more ergonomic way to do this without generics.  The workarounds that work for non-template literal types, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729), don't seem to work here.  So hopefully microsoft/TypeScript#41620 will eventually be implemented and autosuggestions will include some sort of entries for pattern template literals.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwE4ILYwLwwOQG0AKAggEqECyAutjAhDKJFANwBQLUAnnAKYwAiASwBu3ANLcOmGNCQCwAcxgAfGGACuqAEbckrdl16CRAHgAqUzjxAAzGIXwBJAPrEAogGVTTz8QCqAYVNfNwA+KQBrCRsYAG8WGASYXFEYORhIjmjzWhhTZIoYbgAPKG4wABM6Ym5QJHLjBDAOABoaJpD4xIB+GAADABIYlIAyfmExCQBfAHpBo24zfLDR+fEOSd7OhIAuXPzCkrLKmEtuaMQUVC2YHoGhmBXxtZnB0-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-XjFMrBJ-yEogRIoTTEjY8A2BkpDsGMsB5IYq8QHCBAODM7A1J479rMYys7IcpydOmABGAAmdzbPsxzZPKEB5GCysdCQEAkCAA)